# How do you maintain element width on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want to maintain the width of an element on hover. Basically, I have put my width properties in array and want to access them when I hover it's element. Here is my code:

```
var tabs = $('.tab-block li').map(function(){
    return $(this).css('width');
}).toArray();
$('.tab-block li').hover(function(){
    $(this).css({'width': tabs[GET_HOVERED_ELEMENT_WIDTH]});
},function(){
    $(this).removeAttr('style');
});
```

Comment: I have a hover event in my css that bolds the text. Thus, adding 1-3 pixels to the tab width. I don't want to do fixed widths because the text changes based on a number of other variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have no idea what you are doing here but you can do something like this:

```
$('.tab-block li').hover(function(){
    $(this).css({'width': tabs[$(this).index()]});
},function(){
    $(this).removeAttr('style');
});
```